# How to access HTML variable in Java-script in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am filling a select list in angularJS. This is the code.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="NewProduct.category" ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in Categories | orderBy:['name']" ng-change="update(NewProduct.category)" required></select>
```

On change it calls update function; which print categoryID.

```
$scope.update = function (value) {
    alert ($scope.NewProduct.category);
};
```

But i want to access both categoryID nad categoryName in this update function.
I tried:

```
$scope.update = function (value) {
    alert ($scope.NewProduct.category.id);
    alert ($scope.NewProduct.category.name);

};
```

But it alerts undefined, undefined.

How to get both categoryID nad categoryName in this update function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="NewProduct.category" ng-options="category as category.name for category in Categories | orderBy:['name']" ng-change="update(NewProduct.category)" required></select>
```

This will store the entire category in NewProduct.category instead of just the id

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to:

```
$scope.update = function(value) {
   alert(value.id);
   alert(value.name);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in to the update function the current category. Access it by the `value` parameter.

```
$scope.update = function (value) {
    alert (value.id);
    alert (value.name);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a object in `ng-options` like

```
ng-options="category as category.name for category in Categories | orderBy:['name']"
```

And you will get complete object in update function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add `toString()` at the end of each value:

```
alert (value.id.toString());
alert (value.name.toString());
```